# Ubuntu 18.04 Server some user apps (ClamAV, CSF) PID file missing in "/var/run", but service active, how?

Tags: 18.04

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 server. When I'm checking CSF (lfd.pid), ClamAV applications PID files on "/var/run/" there's no such a file (including ClamAV sub-folder). But when I run `sudo service clamav-daemon status` and `sudo service csf status` I can see that those services active, below is an example.

```
root@server:~#  sudo service csf status
● csf.service - ConfigServer Firewall & Security - csf
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/csf.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2020-05-05 11:45:34 +0530; 10h ago
 Main PID: 768 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 1108)
   CGroup: /system.slice/csf.service
```

How do I find these services PID files? Is it permission error or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/var/run/PID` file is created by the service itself, if it finds it useful (to the service). Not all services create a `/var/run/PID` file.

Read `man pgrep;man ps`.